# Funcion php para exportar y importar (actualizar) base de datos mysql

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, sql

Estoy queriendo hacer una función para exportar e importar tablas de base de datos `mysql` desde el sistemas pos creado en entorno web.

Esto se debe a que mi cliente prefiere trabajar de forma offline. Pero existen casos que debe cambiar la PC desktop a una Laptop en el caso que necesite vender sus productos fuera de su Negocio. Y allí es que se necesita una forma mas sencilla para la exportación e importación de datos.

¿Existe algún comando o código para exportación e importación?

Agradezco mucho con solo saber si existe o no la manera de hacerlo

Comment: Revisa [mysqldump](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqldump.html), no es una función de php, sino un comando (ejecutable).

Comment: Si nunca vas a tener la situación en que se hagan ventas en ambos dispositivos puedes usar phpmyadmin, adminer, mysqldump o algo similar para respaldar la base de datos más reciente y cargarla en el dispositivo que se va a utilizar (lo cual a la larga es bastante engorroso y propenso a errores). Si puede darse el caso contrario (ventas en ambos dispositivos) necesitas la versión online.

Comment: Bueno, no se haran ventas en ambos dispositivos. No lo quiero hacer por phpmyadmin o adminer es porque es un poco complicado para mi cliente. Entonces pense en crear una funcion que lo simplifique el trabajo.

Comment: aqui hay un ejemplo de export con php puro [example](https://github.com/BryR0/Examples-STACKOVERFLOW) no se si funcione aun...